# Fixing time sequences which have errors in R

Tags: r, datetime, data-cleaning

I'm working with a date/time sequence (T1,T2...T10) which often have data entry errors due to the data entry person mixing up 12 and 24 hour clocks or mixing up the date.  Is there are R package or code that will detect and fix this?

Below is a sample data frame

```
library(lubridate)

T1<-ymd_hms(c('2022-07-30 12:06:22',  '2021-07-30 13:10:59', '2021-07-30 14:58:58', '2021-07-15 23:50:59'))
T2<-ymd_hms(c('2022-07-30 12:07:22',  NA, '2021-07-30 15:30:18', '2021-07-15 23:58:59'))
T3<-ymd_hms(c('2022-07-30 12:26:22',  '2021-07-30 13:30:59', '2021-07-30 15:48:58', '2021-07-16 12:01:57'))
T4<-ymd_hms(c('2022-07-30 13:46:22',  '2021-07-30 14:11:59', '2021-07-30 16:28:58', '2021-07-16 00:50:59'))

df<- data.frame(T1,T2,T3, T4)
rownames(df)<-c("a","b","c","d")

df$TimeSeqCheck<- ifelse(
  (is.na(df$T1)| 
     is.na(df$T2)| 
     ((df$T2 - df$T1)>= 0))
  &
    (is.na(df$T3) | 
       is.na(df$T2)|
       ((df$T3 - df$T2)>= 0))
  &
    (is.na(df$T4) |
       is.na(df$T3) |
       ((df$T4 - df$T3) >= 0)) 
  , "Good", "Bad" )
```

Note that [d,T3] is not in sequence from T1 to T4, the correct entry should be 2021-07-16 00:01:57.

I was able to create a `ifelse` that labels bad time sequences so they can be excluded, but it would be nice to fix them and not have to exclude data.

I'd appreciate any suggestions as I have been thinking about this for months and have not found a solution.  Note: the actual data set has ~100 000 rows with 10 date/time objects per row.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (at least with your reproducible example):

```
checkingDatetimes <- function(x){
  index <- diff.POSIXt(x = as.POSIXct(x))
  
  return(ifelse(test = any(index < 0, na.rm = TRUE), 
                yes = "Bad", no = "Good"))
}

apply(df[,paste0("T", 1:4)], 1, checkingDatetimes)
```